# one to one between Application and User mongodb

Tags: mongodb, relationship

I want to design the following process in mongodb:

- an applicant can submit an Application
- this Application, if accepted by the admin, can becomes a special User (which is a user with extended fields compare to a normal user)

Because the application can be refused by the admin and the all process is in 2 distincts steps, I think that I should use reference between Application and User instead of embedding them.

Any input to design this process?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting as simply as possible you can have a base User object like so.

```
{
  "type": "user",
  "userInfo" : {}, // Name, email, date created,  etc
  "role": "pending",
}
```

Then it would be possible for the admin to update the users role to `member`, `poweruser` etc.

Then you can have a separate database with a list of permissions like so.

```
[
  {
    "role": "pending",
    "permissions": []
  },
  {
    "role": "member",
    "permissions": [ // a few permissions ]
  },
  {
    "role": "poweruser",
    "permissions": [ // More permissions ]
  },
]
```

This would allow you to have a lookup table of permissions for each user. With the added  benefit that you can update permissions for all users in one database.